# XCode 4.5 app crashes on iOS 4.3 devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have used iOS 4.3 simulator from old xcode version and installed it to my current xcode 4.5 to run an application developed using iOS SDK 6.0. It is crashing so I updated the iOS 4.3 simulator from the preferences in xcode 4.5 then it worked just fine.

I guess I will ask the users to do so but is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Why are the users using the simulator in the first place? o,0

Comment: they are using iOS 4.3 and complaining that the app is crashing so I installed the simulator sdk from an old xcode version and put it inside the simulators directory in the latest version of xcode

Comment: You can't reproduce the crash in the simulator?

Comment: None of this makes any sense. Why would users running iOS 4.3 on their iOS devices be asked to install a simulator? They wouldn't. You need to use Xcode and test the app against a device with iOS 4.3 or use the 4.3 simulator from Xcode 4.5 (not some hacked version from an older Xcode).

Comment: yes I am using the official xcode 4.5 simulator and there is no crash, Also I cannot use a device with iOS 4.3 as I do not have one right now

Comment: Get your users to send you their crash logs if you can't duplicate the crash in the simulator.

Comment: Some of them already sent crash logs and I was using PresentViewController which is available only for iOS 5.0 and later, I changed that to PresentModalViewController and I hope no more crashes to occur.

Comment: That should have been easily reproducible in the simulator...here is a tip though:  If you don't have a device with the target OS to test on, then you can't claim to support that OS.